# Failed to restore data from temp talbe in greenDao

Tags: android, database, upgrade, greendao

When I use tempTable to upgrade the GreenDaoDB ,but it occurs a problem leads to data loss

Faided to restore data from temp Table
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373170/greendao-schema-update-and-data-migration/30334668#30334668 I just use the answer to upgrade my GreenDaoDB,but  occurs the above question

Comment: oh,It is save my day.. .many thanks,